# User input handling in Java GUI program

Tags: java, user-interface, exception, applet

i have written an applet and i want to receive an input(for example a number) from the user.i mean, first a component appears and ask from the user to enter a number.after that, if the number was negative, a component appear and say "the input is wrong", and finally the first component appear again and ask the input from user.how can i do that?
I tried with try-catch block but the component just appears two times if the number is negative.

Comment: First, please show your code. Second, applets have been deprecated since Java 9 and have been removed in Java 11. If using applets is not a requirement, consider using JFrames.

Comment: I just want to receive user input with a component and handle it, i have said applet because the program should be written in an applet.but the aim is that i said.the code is too long and does not help the topic to be answered.

Comment: *"but the component just appears two times"* Rather than 'the code' as suggested by @Nosrep post a [mre] that demonstrates the behavior described. Agree with avoiding applets.Most people who could help can no longer run them locally. Is this AWT based, or can you use Swing? It's much easier with Swing (`JOptionPane` & `JSpinner`). Never mind, the MRE will tell us details like that.